# How to move (ICSDroid) Calendars to the Phone section

Tags: applications, sync, calendar

This questions splits **[this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135727/searching-for-a-way-using-ics-calendar-files-from-dropbox)** question into smaller parts. *Living without Google*

So first of all I would like to find out, how I can move the 2 **ICSDroid** calendars to the **Phone** section. I think with doing this the read-only issue will be solved, too.

[image: after adding 2 ics files]
<sup>After adding 2 `.ics` files (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Feel free to post also alternatives to ICSDroid if there is something better. It does not have to be ICSDroid for the import.

Comment: Hm, sticking to your [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154), are you? Your first line seems to approve my suspicion. OK, let me give you a pointer to check with: [Android without Google](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-1) is a blog series of mine, covering calendar/contact sync as well. To your convenience, these articles are not only available in English, but in German as well ;)

Comment: Not really XY problem ;) And sure with owncloud it would work. But I really liked the idea to go without. But I see that there is no way for this right now. So I gonna setup an Owncloud server now. But maybe someone still has an idea in the future.

Comment: Mustn't necessarily be owCloud (though it has its added values). If you're just after contacts & calendars, there's also Baïkal as plain DAV server, and some other lightweight variants like [Radicale](http://radicale.org/). See our sister site: [Simple self-hosted sync system for Android contacts and calendar events](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28165/185)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved with installing **ownCloud** on my server. It was not difficult and is easy to setup. Also it gives the possibility to enable even more features.

So in Thunderbird I just add the online calendar URL to the specific calendar. That's it. The only bad thing is that Thunderbird(Lightning) does not get the colors from the server. So you have to set them manually.

And on Android you need a special app like **CalDAV** which is really cheap and as well easy to setup.

Now you can use any calendar app like the of your Android. Planner Plus or aCalendar. This is totally up to you. I really like **Planner Plus** somehow.

For me this is a really good solution. Synching is working perfectly even with different users on it at the same time. You can also manage the rights the users have in your ownCloud which was impossible with the row ics Dropbox solution.

I also use the Tasks app of ownCloud, what is called the app **OpenTasks** under Android, which makes it pretty easy also to use tasks on Android.